# Using multiple delimiters with StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I'd like to know how I can use multiple delimiters with StringTokenizer in java.
For example one of these `!,*,/,^` will occur as a delimiter. Also there will only be one at a time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [constructor with two arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), where the second is the delimiters.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(yourString, "!*^/");
```

Comment: He's asking of multiple delimiters.

Comment: @Mob yup this is the way.. in here all the 4 !,*,/,^ are defined as !*^/

Comment: Can you make a delimiter that has more than one character e.g., AVG?

Answer (score 4):

You can use String.split() method because it takes regex as a parameter. You can specify Regex such that it can split the string based upon one of these deliminators.

Comment: Except it can't be used for large strings.