# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am using the Netbeans IDE for my code. I am getting this error when I try to run it:"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8589.416,5468.2407,4263.4077,4064.9358,1997.893,5282.325,2169.72,2773.4211,7526.386,4607.6763,2598.06,1522.6462,1300.5988,1181.63,Tumor"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at Preprocessing.Newsvm_scale.run(Newsvm_scale.java.java:150)
    at Preprocessing.Newsvm_scale.main(Newsvm_scale.java.java:332)
```

I keep in mind that the other similar questions here couldn't helped me since I have a different code. My code is below. If anyone can point me in the right direction I will be incredibly grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Debug your code, go to line 540 and take a look at the parameter of ``Double.parseDouble``. It's a huge string, not a single number. That cannot be parsed to a ``Double``.

Comment: I don't think `8589.416,5468.2407,4263.4077,4064.9358,1997.893,5282.325,2169.72,2773.4211,7526.386,4607.6763,2598.06,1522.6462,1300.5988,1181.63,Tumor` is a number either.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It includes the actual string that you were trying to parse, and it *clearly* is not a valid decimal number.

Comment: And please, see [ask]. And more important, provide a [mcve]. There is way to many code here..

Answer (score 0):

The StringTokenizer method has set one long string to the value st, which is not being broken up. So when the Double
Parse method is being called. It throws a Number format exception, because it is trying to convert that string to a double. You need to specify that commas separate the numbers when calling the StringTokenizer method.
Feel free to ask if you like some more assistance.

Comment: ...or you could add to your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot@jordanH. yes the file that I used is commas separate delimited. but I could not understand you, what do you mean by (you need to specify that commas separate the numbers). can you explain more? thank you

Comment: When you instantiate the StringTokenizer object you should specify the character that is used to seperate the tokens. In this case the tokens are seperated by commas. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446704/using-multiple-delimiters-with-stringtokenizer StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(stringName, ","); where the comma signifies the delimiter.

Comment: I try to do as you suggest me@JordanH ( StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," ,");) . But still faced the same error